# Rewrite rule on multiple variables using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am pretty rookie on that and would like to know how to rewrite with .htaccess an url http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=21&page=164 to say http://www.example.com/de/value-added-tax/, where "de" refers to german language and "value-added-tax" refers to page id no 64. I also have css and image files that need to keep on working (e.g. ./img/logo.png). There are couple of other *.php files too that need to keep on working (e.g. search.php). The hosting server is Apache.

Comment: you cannot rewrite like this ...

Comment: You would have to have built rewriting like this into your application as you create it. mod_rewrite doesn't have access to your database and so it has no way of knowing what the id to keyword relation is. If this was something built into the system, it would be able to parse the URI and get keywords and then search the database to convert them back into ids, setup whatever variables it needs and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rewrite as you ask ... sorry, **Apache does not have access to your database**. You cannot ask it to query on the names and giving back the IDs ...

But maybe you can try something like this :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(search\.php|img/|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(/?)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

This will work with `mydomain.tld/xx/zzz-zzz` and `mydomain.tld/xx/zzz-zzz/`
This will redirect everything like that, except if it starts with `search.php`, or `img/` or `robots.txt`

- `xx` = 2 letters in lowercase
- `zzz-zzz` = All alphanumerics and the `-`

This will work with trailing slash, and without it at the end of the address

**But you have to modify your script to search by page name and no more by page id, same for languages**

Hope it helped !